# Google Maps API 2 for Android “Unfortunately, [app] has stopped.” Unable to run the app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

I'm a newbie to android programming and I've run through the android developers guide and YouTube guides ,and  also checked the other similar questions asked here, but am still unable to load a map on AVD emulator. I have also imported google-play-services_lib and 
*Android build target* : **Android 4.2.2 API 17**

I'm able to install my app successfully on emulator but  every time when I try to run it, it gives the notification of "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped."

Any attempt to help would be much appreciated.
here's my code:

**manifest.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.sitemarker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
    android:name="com.android.sitemarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.sitemarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                                                                                                                
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.sitemarker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" />
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

**main.xml file:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />




    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java file:**

```
package com.android.sitemarker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-31 08:33:33.989: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: Please dont provide your api key..

Comment: @JaiKumar now this will not matter

Comment: Will you post your LogCat

Comment: Did you install Google Play Service lib??

Comment: please provide full log trace.

Comment: that is the only LogCat....and yes I have installed Google Play Service lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play Services are not currently available for virtual devices, although with a bit of googling, it looks like there are ways round it.

Your best bet is to just use a real device if you have one available, and make sure you install Google Play Services :)

Comment: I think you're supposed to use a Fragment class. You will probably need to read up on that, as I don't fully understand Fragments.

If it doesn't work on a real device, I would say to either review your Fragment, or that Google Play Services isn't set up properly

Hope you get it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Google map run on real device it will not run on emulator so try in real device if it will   not run on real device then try this code and you also properly check that you add  googleplay library in your project properties

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
double latitude=17.385044;
double longitude=78.486671;
private String provider;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 LocationManager service=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean enableGPS= service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean enableWifi=service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
 // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
     // go to the settings
 if(!enableGPS){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gps signal not found",1).show();
    Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

 // Initialize the location fields
 if (location != null) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     onLocationChanged(location);
 } else {

     //do something
 }


try {
    //loading map
    initilizeMap();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
   private void initilizeMap(){
if(googleMap==null){
googleMap=(MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();    
      //check if map is created succesfully or not
    if(googleMap==null){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sorry unable to create map",0).show();  
    }
}
```

MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
CameraPosition cameraPosition=new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(17.385044,     78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
     googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(null);
      }

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
initilizeMap();
 }

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
double lat =  location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat+","+lng,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + coordinate.latitude+","+coordinate.longitude,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Marker startPerc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(coordinate)
.title("Start")
.snippet("Inizio del percorso")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
}


  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }


  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
```